# Creating DOJO buttons with Javascript function causing conflicts in buttons created

Tags: javascript, button, dojo

my apologies for any mistake in english, I am brazilian.

I have a website with DOJO library, I use it in many things.

I am having some dificulty to create buttons in javascript.

I wrote a function to create the buttons, it is working, creating buttons.

**But, when a new button is created, the former button lost the event "onclick".**

It can be viewed here: http://jsbin.com/xuzevi/edit?html,js,output

To create the button, I used this code:

```
require([ 'dojo/dom', 'dojo/parser', 'dijit/form/Button', 'dojo/domReady!' ], 
        function( dom, parser, Button)
        {
            var div_Compra = document.getElementById(p_Div);
            if( ! div_Compra ) { console.log('ERRO - div_Compra: '+p_Div); return false; }

            var botao = new Button({ label: '' });
            if( ! botao ) { console.log('ERRO - botao'); return false; }

            botao.startup();
            botao.set('iconClass', 'dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconSelectAll');
            botao.set('showLabel', false);
            botao.placeAt(div_Compra);
            botao.on('click', function() { Mensagem(p_Indice); }); 
        }
);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please include code in your question that can be used to re-create your error. Read the following documentation http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, the code is here: http://www.angar27.com.br/zzz/CPR_Compra.js. Clicking the link will show the source code.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and also see this "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time." here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hi. I added the JSBIN link. thanks for the comment.

Comment: Welcome to SO and good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not in the above mentioned code. Main problem is your usage of `innerHTML` in `CPR_Compra.Cadastro` method. You cannot think, the dojo dijits as just HTML tags, they are DOM objects, nodes and more. When you updated the `div_Cadastro.innerHTML`, it kind of destroyed the wigit, but retained the HTML tags, so the onclick event stopped working.

Instead of using `innerHTML` use `appendChild`, that way the dom nodes wont be destroyed. below is the JSBin with working implementation.

http://jsbin.com/butacuquza/edit?js,output

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

from https://davidwalsh.name/dojo-widget

- To create a widget programmatically, you create DOM nodes which act as placeholders for the future widget

and read this: https://davidwalsh.name/dojo-behavior

- Widget Creation with dojo.behavior

  - Widget creation is an even better opportunity to use dojo.behavior:

Answer (score 0):

for others who came to here like me, a few more links:

HTML DOM appendChild() Method

- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

The `Node.appendChild()` method adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent node.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild